# Reading Input Error

Tags: c++, input, scanf

I am working on NOV14 on COdechef contest problems. and i stuck at this problem.
http://www.codechef.com/NOV14/problems/RBTREE
My algorithm working well, but i cant take the input correctly.  the problem is  i don't know how many number of inputs are given. but i need to store in multiple variables.
Take a look at here..

`5
Qb 4 5
Qr 4 5
Qi
Qb 4 5
Qr 4 5`

where 5 is the number of test cases,
can i read every test cases into variables.
if i take First test case I can take Qb to one variable, 4 to other and 5 to another.
But the problem is How to read a line which start with Qi.

Comment: You need to read the query command (Qb, Qr, Qi) and interpret it. Depending on the case you read arguments or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, if you write C++, you should use C++ streams. Here's the code for input (which you can adjust for your own needs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file;
  file.open("data.in");
  int lines = 0;
  file >> lines;
  std::string query_type;
  for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    file >> query_type;
    if (query_type == "Qi") {
      std::cout << query_type << std::endl;
    } else {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0; 
      file >> x >> y;
      std::cout << query_type << " " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    }
  }
  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check what you've read at each step, and then determine whether or not you need to read the numbers in.

So read two characters, and if the characters you've read are "Q" and "i", you don't need to read any numbers, and you can just step on to the next line. Otherwise, you should read the two numbers before going to the next line.